# VBA excel - reading an nxn range in excel as an array

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I have the following test in my excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to be able to read the range as an array.

```
Period CAt1 Cat2 Cat3 Cat4
    0   A   B   C   D
    1   E   F   g   h
    2   l   k   d   i
    3   m   B   dsfasd  D
    4   n   a   C   D
    5   o   B   fs  D
    6   p   B   C   D
    7   q   B   df  D
    8   r   B   fas D
    9   s   B   fad D
    10  Test Deal   B   dsfasd  D
    11  u   B   C   D
```

I've made a range name for this call Check. I'm trying the following code, it works for a 2-d array. I want it to work on an abstract number based on the range name. I've tried adjusting it to work. The idea is that I want to call the row so that my udt can be able to read at a Period the Category value.

So in my main():

```
Sub Tst()
Dim Temp As Variant
Temp = Check("Initialise")
Debug.Print Check("0")
End Sub

Function Check(getItem As String)
    Static CapitalFactors(362, 2)
    Static Counter As Integer
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim exitflag As Boolean
    Dim Response As Integer
    Dim Wsheet As String
    Dim TopRow As Integer
    Dim LeftCol As Integer
    exitflag = False
    If getItem = "Initialise" Then
        I = 1
        j = 1
        For Each cell In Range("Check")
            CapitalFactors(I, j) = cell
            j = j + 1
             If j > 2 Then
                j = 1
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next
        'Range("InputMonitor").ClearContents
    Counter = 0
    Else
        I = 0
        Do Until I = UBound(CapitalFactors, 1) Or exitflag = True
            I = I + 1
            If UCase(CapitalFactors(I, 1)) = UCase(getItem) Then
                Check = CapitalFactors(I, 2)
                exitflag = True
                'If CapitalFactors(I,[Customized CashFlow Flag] = "No" Then Debug.Print 1 'GoSub SheetHighlight
            End If
        Loop
        If exitflag = False Then Response = MsgBox("Parameter -" & getItem & "- not found", vbCritical)
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: Why not `Temp = Range(MyWhateverRange).Value`. Excel will automatically create an array for you

Comment: You may want to see [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Mind BLOWN!!! I had no idea it would do that! Talk about over-engineering! How do I close this question out. Those were the perfect awnsers, thank you.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Only problem with this route, is that I want the array to start at 0 not at 1. The following code before your line makes it unable to assign the value. Dim Temp (0 To 360, 1 To 10) As Variant. Where as if left as Dim Temp as Variant, the resulting array is Temp(1 to 361, 1 to 10)

Comment: Yes unfortunately you cannot change that behavior. Best to use `For i = Lbound(Ar) to Ubound(Ar)` This way you do not need to check whether it is `0` or `1` :)